# Getting unexpected token: n when parsing JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Grabbing innerHTMl of this div

```
<div style="display:none;" id="graphdata">{n:2 , e:1},{from:1 , to:2},{from:2, to:3},{from:3, to:4}</div>
```

then parsing it with this JS code

```
jdiv=document.getElementById('graphdata').innerHTML;
edges=JSON.parse(jdiv);
```

JS console in Chrome says:
Uncaught SyntaxError: `Unexpected token n`

can't find out where is that token n can be and what's wrong with my code?
any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to quote your labels and add brackets...

```
[
    {
        "n": 2,
        "e": 1
    },
    {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 2
    },
    {
        "from": 2,
        "to": 3
    },
    {
        "from": 3,
        "to": 4
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to take the value, split it by ',' to create an array and use JSON.stringify to generate a correct JSON. From there you can use JSON.parse and have an object